# How to create a if-statement using Pandas, get last row of csv and extract at a specific col, IF col is empty, check line before it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know if I can create an if-statement to check if the very last row at a specific cell to see if it contains any data or if it is "nan".
If it contains data then proceed, if not, I want the program to check the line right before the last.

Here is the code I am using so far, using csv data found on github:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import requests


url1 = r"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/owid/covid-19-data/master/public/data/vaccinations/country_data/Austria.csv"

file1 = pd.read_csv(url1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[:,:].values)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(file1.iloc[-1:,:].values)


# This line gets the last row of csv file
Austria_date = df1.iloc[:,1]

# This line gets the cell of the last row, but unforatenly it does not contain data, instead "nan"
Austria_cum = df1.iloc[:, 4].map('{:,}'.format)
```

Is it possible to create an if-statement to check the previous line and see if that contains data?

Comment: `file1.dropna().tail(1).iloc[0,4]` is much simpler

Comment: @RobRaymond Thanks! This is by far the most effective solution I have seen so far, and I've been researching for hours... Could you explain in simple english what in effect this is doing?

Comment: `dropna()` - removes rows that have any blanks - you don't want these.  Simplest way to get last row is `tail(1)`

Comment: @RobRaymond Got it. Do you know of any way to wrap the line: file1.dropna().tail(1).iloc[0,4], into a DataFrame object? I am trying to use to Pandas to_string method on it but am receiving the error message:     ```"DATE": [Austria_date.to_string(header=None, index=None)],```

```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to_string'```

Comment: `file1.dropna().tail(1)` is a DF object,  you can reference columns by name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just care about getting the data from the last line where it is filled you could use:

```py
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

It will turn the following df:

| Date | Vaccinations |
| --- | --- |
| 17-2-21 | 10 |
| 18-2-21 | 20 |
| 19-2-21 | NaN |

Into:

| Date | Vaccinations |
| --- | --- |
| 17-2-21 | 10 |
| 18-2-21 | 20 |
| 19-2-21 | 20 |

Do note that this fills all the `NaN` values, for more info see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html

Edit:

I have changed my example to reflect the different results that my method has compared to Rob Raymond's method. If you want your result to be `Date: 18-2-21, Vaccinations: 20`, you should go with Rob Raymond's method of handling missing values. If you want the result to be `Date: 19-2-21, Vaccinations: 20` you should go with the method described in this answer.